# What is the least available Python 3.5 version and where to find it?

Tags: appveyor

Until now we used C:\Python341 and C:\Python341-x64. Now we want to update our AppVeyor tests to Python 3.5. But C:\Python350 does not work, neither C:\Python350-x64. What is the least supported Python 3.5 version and where to find the information next time? Where is the list of available python images (I could not find even any reference to C:\Python341 in AppVeyor docs)

Answer (score -1):

The latest Python 3.5.x available in AppVeyor environment is 3.5.4 and it's installed into `C:\Python35` and `C:\Python35-x64` directories.

Comment: Yeah, but I want the lowest Python 3.5.x available

Comment: @aleskva Why do you need the lowest Python 3.5.x available? Why not use the  installed version (either through the path given or possibly through `C:\Python354` at least if the latest directory is available, I didn't check this).

Comment: Because it is the least supported version by my package. So I want to test it obviously. C:\Python354 does not work

Comment: OK, sorry I didn't get the question correctly. You can install the required version of Python 3.5.x during the build by adopting this script we use to build VM images: https://github.com/appveyor/build-images/blob/master/scripts/Windows/install_python.ps1#L218-L250. You can find available Python 3.5 Windows distros here: https://www.python.org/downloads/